# Is it possible to wrap a flow type in an immutable container?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

For example, given the following record:

```js
type UserRecord = {
  id: string;
  name: ?string;
  age: number;
}
```

Is there some way to do the equivalent of the following:

```js
/* @flow */

import { List, Map } from 'immutable'

const users: List<Map<UserRecord>> = List();    
let user: Map<UserRecord>;

user = Map({ id: '666', age: 30 });
users.push(user);
```

Otherwise I end up simply using something like `Map<string, any>` which I think takes away from using Immutable.js with the Flow type system.

Comment: Note that there's a WIP immutable.js flow interface that you would need to include manually into your project. I don't know if it works well, or at all. See https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow and https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/203

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is not possible since records and maps have very different semantics. Map type is parameterized with types of of key and value, so when you call `.get` you will get the same type for all keys.

There is a way around, though:

```
declare class Map<T, K1=null, V1=null, K2=null, V2=null> {

  constructor(val: T): void;

  get(key: K1 & $Keys<T>): V1;
  get(key: K2 & $Keys<T>): V2;
  // etc
}

const m: Map<{ foo: string, bar: number }, 'foo', string, 'bar', number> = new Map({
  'foo': 'foo',
  bar: 42
});


m.get('foo') // string
m.get('bar') // number
m.get('baz') // error
```

It's probably a good idea to generate such declaration with some sort of script to support desired amount of key-value pairs.

Such declaration is a a bit verbose, but safe if you don't mess up type parameters. A couple of comments:

- we use recent Flow feature that allows us to declare default type parameter, so that we could use a single declaration for any number of key-value pairs;
- `K1 & $Keys<T>` ensures that we can only use actual keys of type `T` to retrieve values; this helps with consistency to some degree, unfortunately, I found no way to verify consistency of value types, so you have to be careful with those.

Comment: It's unfortunate that there isn't anything less verbose available to us—thanks for the interesting workaround